# Pytest's capsys.disabled() not working as expected

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using Pytest 3.1.3, which should have the `disabled()` method for the `capsys` fixture described in https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html. I'm trying use it in the following simplified test:

```
import pytest

def test_capsys(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():
        print("foo")
    print("bar")
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == "bar\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

However, apparently my assertion is not correct:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_capsys __________________________________

capsys = <_pytest.capture.CaptureFixture object at 0x102741ef0>

    def test_capsys(capsys):
        with capsys.disabled():
            print("foo")
        print("bar")
        out, err = capsys.readouterr()
>       assert out == "bar\n"
E    AssertionError: assert '' == 'bar\n'
E      + bar

try_capsys.py:8: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
bar
=========================== 1 failed in 0.03 seconds ===========================
```

Note that if I comment out the `with` block, the test passes. I don't understand: shouldn't the `with` block have no effect on the `capsys.readouterr()`?

**Update**

This problem seems to be the same as described in this issue: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1993.